# A Jacobi elliptic integral with cosine

Tags: definite-integrals, elliptic-functions, elliptic-integrals

After reduction of a problem, I find myself in front of these integrals,
$$
\int_0^{2\pi} cn \left( \frac{2K(1/2)}{\pi} \theta, \frac{1}{2} \right) \cos(m \theta) \mathrm{d}\theta,
$$
with $m$ positive integers. For now,

- I think it vanishes for $m$ even,
- I am not sure how to get the value for $m=1$,
- I am also not sure whether an expansion of $\cos(m\theta)$ then integration by parts would yield something nice (in terms of the case $m=1$ hopefully).

I would like to hear your thoughts on these ones!

Comment: $\S 22.11$ of [DLMF](https://dlmf.nist.gov/22.11) has several formula for the Fourier series of Jacobi elliptic functions,

Comment: Thank you, I'm looking into it, that might be helpful!

Comment: It worked out, I posted the answer for anyone's interest

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed by @achille hui, the Fourier series of Jacobi elliptic functions are known. In particular here,
$$
cn \left( \frac{2K(1/2)}{\pi} \theta, \frac{1}{2} \right) = \frac{2\sqrt{2}\pi}{K(1/2)} \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{e^{-(n+1/2)\pi}}{1+e^{-(2n+1)\pi}} \cos ((2n+1) \theta),
$$
in turn,
$$
\int_0^{2\pi} cn \left( \frac{2K}{\pi} \theta, \frac{1}{2} \right) \cos(m \theta) \mathrm{d}\theta = \begin{cases}
\frac{2\sqrt{2}}{K(1/2)} \frac{e^{-m\pi/2}}{1+e^{-m\pi}} \pi^2 &\textrm{if $m$ is odd}\\
0 &\textrm{otherwise} 
\end{cases}
$$